# How to merge variables without using additional space?

Tags: python, pytorch

I currently have two feature files, each with a size of 3GB, and an 8GB machine. Now, I want to load both files into memory one after the other and merge them into a single variable. I would like to know how to do this without exceeding the available memory. I tried using `torch.cat` , but it seems that the `cat` function might allocate additional memory for merging, which leads to memory overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a high-level outline of the process:

1. Open and Read Files Sequentially: Instead of loading both files into memory simultaneously, read them one after the other.
2. Process in Chunks
3. Close and Release Resources
4. Repeat: Continue reading, processing, and merging chunks until you have processed the entire files.

Here's a Python code snippet illustrating this approach:

```
merged_data = []

# Process the first file
with open('file1.txt', 'rb') as file1:
    while True:
        chunk = file1.read(1024)  # Read 1MB at a time (adjust chunk size as needed)
        if not chunk:
            break  # End of file
        merged_data.append(chunk)

# Process the second file
with open('file2.txt', 'rb') as file2:
    while True:
        chunk = file2.read(1024)  # Read 1MB at a time (adjust chunk size as needed)
        if not chunk:
            break  # End of file
        merged_data.append(chunk)

# Merge the chunks into a single variable
final_data = b''.join(merged_data)

# Now 'final_data' contains the merged content of both files
```